# Service Worker. How to use cache in low connection

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Now my `sw.js` looks like this:

```
importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/workbox-cdn@4.3.1/workbox/workbox-sw.js')

// --------------------------------------------------
// Configure
// --------------------------------------------------

// Set workbox config
workbox.setConfig({
  "debug": true
})

// Start controlling any existing clients as soon as it activates
workbox.core.clientsClaim()

// Skip over the SW waiting lifecycle stage
workbox.core.skipWaiting()

workbox.precaching.cleanupOutdatedCaches()

// --------------------------------------------------
// Precaches
// --------------------------------------------------

// Precache assets

// --------------------------------------------------
// Runtime Caching
// --------------------------------------------------

// Register route handlers for runtimeCaching
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://fonts.googleapis.com/.*'), new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
  "cacheableResponse": {
    "statuses": [0, 200]
  }
}), 'GET')
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://fonts.gstatic.com/.*'), new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
  "cacheableResponse": {
    "statuses": [0, 200]
  }
}), 'GET')
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://.*.tile.osm.org/.*'), new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
  "cacheableResponse": {
    "statuses": [0, 200]
  }
}), 'GET')
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/.*'), new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
  "cacheableResponse": {
    "statuses": [0, 200]
  }
}), 'GET')
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/_nuxt/'), new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({}), 'GET')
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/'), new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({}), 'GET')
```

Works perfectly offline, as expected.

But when I am online and my connection is very weak (for example, I am far from the WI-FI router), then I continue to receive data over the network, but the download, of course, is extremely slow.

I still could not find a way to use the cache for a bad connection, or for a long server response time.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the only change you need to implement is to change the route handlers for both `/_nuxt/` and `/` to also use the `CacheFirst()` strategy instead of the current `NetworkFirst()`:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/_nuxt/'), new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({}), 'GET')
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/'), new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({}), 'GET')
```

I am not sure if you can make that strategy dynamic based on the *current* connection of the user, but you could check the connection speed of the user via 
`navigator.connection.effectiveType`, whose value would be one of `['4g', '3g', '2g', 'slow-2g']` and then initiate the caching strategy based on that.

**Note!** I'm not sure if this one-time check on initial load is a good practise/idea, since the user could easily have their connection speed increased and then maybe in that scenario you'd want them to benefit from the `NetworkFirst()` strategy.

For a more elaborate example, you can check out Cloudinary's custom workbox plugin [here](https://github.com/tpiros/cloudinary-workbox-example/blob/master/app/sw.js) and a great [tutorial](https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/adaptive-image-caching-based-on-network-speed-with-workbox-js/) on this subject.